# Spring batch Where to generate PDF files whit statistics of all read items

Tags: spring-batch

In a spring batch project I must generate several PDF files with statistical information on all the processed items (for example three items contain the number one, two items contain the number two ...), as the information is generated after reading all the items I thought about use the afterJob method obtaining the information through queries to a database in which I would be saving the read items, but from what I have read afterjob method is recommended to use it for Notifications and Cleanup files I have not seen examples doing other operations, which would be the recommended place to generate these pdf files ?

Thanks!

Comment: You may add one more step specifically to generate pdf with the statistics collected during the job flow

Comment: @Luca Basso Ricci ,Thank you for your answer, I added a tasklet step